# How to show if a sequence diverges to infinity then it has no limit point?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, general-topology, limits, convergence-divergence

Consider a set of numbers in a divergent sequence $x_n$.

My deduction:
If a set has no limit point, then there does not exist any sequence in the set that converges.
Then if {$x_n$} has no limit point, then $\forall$ subsequences of $x_n$, $x_{n_k}$ diverges.
Note that the proof of the theorem 
$``$**Every subsequence of a sequence diverging to infinity diverges to infinity** $"$
involves the assumption that $n_k > k$ which is not the case here, since $n_k$ 
 is not necessarily increasing.
So, how do you prove there is no limit point in a $x_n$.
(PS: you may use the theorem above after proving $n_k$ diverges)

By diverge, I mean diverge to infinity.

Comment: Divergent sequence, or divergent to infinity? There's a slight difference

Comment: Not every subsequence of a divergent sequence is divergent.

Comment: You should clarify whether by "diverging" you automatically mean "diverging to infinity", because there are other kinds of non-convergence which are all usually referred to as "divergence" (e.g. oscillation).

Comment: _'If a set has no limit point, then there does not exist any sequence in the set that converges.'_ -- how about a set $\{0\} $ and a costant sequence $(0, 0, 0 \ldots ) $? The set is a singleton, so it has no limit point but a sequence is obviously convergent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not clear what you mean by a divergent sequence, but from what you have written it appears that your sequence $x_n \to \infty $. If possible let there be a limit point $a$. Consider the interval $(a-1,a+1)$. For all $n$ sufficiently large, $x_n >a+1$ so $x_n \notin (a-1,a+1)$. This contradicts the definition of limit point.

Comment: But how does this prove there is no $x_n \in (a-1, a+1)$, or in general, $(a-\delta, a+\delta)$ other than $a$ itself?

Comment: If $a$ is a limit point then any interval $(a-\delta,a+\delta)$ must contain $x_n$ for  infinitely many values of $n$.

Answer (score 2):

The statement is not necessarily true:

Let $$a_{2n}=1-\frac{1}{2n},$$ 
$$a_{2n+1}={2n+1}$$

This is a sequence that is divergent, yet has a limit point - namely $1$.

Comment: Yes, I should clarify that by diverge I meant diverge to infinity.